# How to solve " DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use "when deploy node application with passenger+nginx

Tags: nginx, deployment, passenger

1. My node application can run normally when I was in development mode. Simply use "npm start" to run it and I could visit my app through "http://localhost:3000"
2. But when I deploy my node application with nginx+passenger, I meet this error,the detailed information is list as below.
3. I notice the key information must be:

   > "DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'"

   but I don't know what does it refer to, because I can't found 'GLOBAL' in my code files;
4. I am sure the passenger was successfully installed and worked normally, because I could run other simple node application through it but not my app, I don't know why......
5. I have struggled for the problems for many many hours and searched google for answers, hope you can give me some useful information.

[image: the error info]

### Information

> Web application could not be started
>     An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a startup response in time. Please read this article for more information about this problem.
>
> ```
> Raw process output:
>
> (node:12671) DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'
> Error ID
> ef585c1b
> Application root
> /var/www/microblog/myblog
> Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
> development
> User and groups
> uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
> Environment variables
> XDG_SESSION_ID=55
> COMP_WORDBREAKS=    
> "'><;|&(:
> TERM=xterm-256color
> SHELL=/bin/bash
> SSH_CLIENT=27.46.7.216 5816 22
> SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/3
> USER=root
> ```
>
> LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
>       MAIL=/var/mail/root
>      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
>       PWD=/var/www/microblog/myblog
>       LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>       NODE_PATH=/usr/share/passenger/node
>       SHLVL=1
>       HOME=/root
>       LANGUAGE=en_US:
>       LOGNAME=root
>       SSH_CONNECTION=27.46.7.216 5816 123.57.243.29 22
>       LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
>       XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
>       LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
>       _=/usr/bin/passenger
>       OLDPWD=/var/www/microblog
>      PASSENGER_LOCATION_CONFIGURATION_FILE=/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
>       PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD=true
>       UID=0
>       SERVER_SOFTWARE=nginx/1.10.1 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.30
>       PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR=/tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXu3bFF4
>       IN_PASSENGER=1
>       PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
>       RAILS_ENV=development
>       RACK_ENV=development
>       WSGI_ENV=development
>       NODE_ENV=development
>       PASSENGER_APP_ENV=development
>       Ulimits
>       Unknown
>
> ```
> System metrics
> ------------- General -------------
> Kernel version    : 3.13.0-86-generic
> Uptime            : 1d 13h 59m 14s
> Load averages     : 0.07%, 0.07%, 0.06%
> Fork rate         : unknown
>
> ------------- CPU -------------
> Number of CPUs    :    1
> Average CPU usage :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
>   CPU 1           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
> I/O pressure      :   0%
>   CPU 1           :   0%
> Interference from other VMs:   0%
>   CPU 1                    :   0%
>
> ------------- Memory -------------
> RAM total         :    992 MB
> RAM used          :    224 MB (23%)
> RAM free          :    767 MB
> Swap total        :      0 MB
> Swap used         :      0 MB (-nan%)
> Swap free         :      0 MB
> Swap in           : unknown
> Swap out          : unknown
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Answer (score 0):

ah~~~~~~the topic i posted was a mistake, "GLOBAL" is just the warning!!! what really matter is that:

- " An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not
  write a startup response in time."

which means my application didn't  start up fast or even did't start up at all.so the problem is in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled .conf file! Because i use express+node mode:

1. The mistake I made is the start file which only worked for node application :`passenger_startup_file app.js`;
2. and it shoule be : `passenger_startup_file bin/www`